# AWS ec2 describe-instance-status only for instances with events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Is there a easy way to run `aws ec2 describe-instance-status` and only display the information of instances if they have any [Scheduled Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-instances-status-check_sched.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `--query` arg for this:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instance-status --query 'InstanceStatuses[?length(Events || `[]`) > `0`]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `--filter` CLI argument for this:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instance-status --filters "Name=event.code,Values='instance-reboot','system-reboot','system-maintenance','instance-retirement','instance-stop'"
```

This filters statuses only down to the ones with events with the specified code. Since this command lists out all possible codes, you basically get only the statuses with one or more events.