# Ruby aws-sdk describe-instance-status only for instances with events

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I would like to use the [ruby aws-sdk client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/Client.html) function [`Aws::EC2::Client.describe-instance-status`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/Client.html#describe_instance_status-instance_method) to only return a list of instances with [Scheduled Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-instances-status-check_sched.html).  Here is my current attempt at this:

```
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new(
  region: ENV['REGION'],
  access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
)

ec2_events = ec2.describe_instance_status({
  dry_run: false,
  filters: [
    {
      name: "events",
      values: ["event.description"],
    },
  ],
})
```

Here is my resulting error message:

```
/Users/myusername/.gems/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.5.11/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:15:in `call': The filter 'events' is invalid (Aws::EC2::Errors::InvalidParameterValue)
    from /Users/myusername/.gems/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.5.11/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_converter.rb:20:in `call'
    from /Users/myusername/.gems/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.5.11/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/response_paging.rb:26:in `call'
    from /Users/myusername/.gems/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.5.11/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:21:in `call'
    from /Users/myusername/.gems/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.5.11/lib/seahorse/client/request.rb:70:in `send_request'
    from /Users/myusername/.gems/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.5.11/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:207:in `block (2 levels) in define_operation_methods'
    from test.rb:30:in `<main>'
```

Is there a simple way to have aws-sdk praise out only the instances with Scheduled Events?  I know that the regular aws cli tool has this [option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39300976/aws-ec2-describe-instance-status-only-for-instances-with-events), but I really want to use the aws-sdk gem instead.

Comment: it says `events` invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused `Name` and `Values` in your code - it should be read as

```
ec2_events = ec2.describe_instance_status({
  dry_run: false,
  filters: [
    {
      name: "event.description",
      values: ["events"],
    },
  ],
})
```

You can check the full documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstanceStatus.html

Filter (`Name`) possible values are

- `availability-zone` - The Availability Zone of the instance.
- `event.code` - The code for the scheduled event (instance-reboot | system-reboot | system-maintenance | instance-retirement | instance-stop).
- `event.description` - A description of the event.
- `event.not-after` - The latest end time for the scheduled event (for example, 2014-09-15T17:15:20.000Z).
- `event.not-before` - The earliest start time for the scheduled event (for example, 2014-09-15T17:15:20.000Z).
- `instance-state-code` - The code for the instance state, as a 16-bit unsigned integer. The high byte is an opaque internal value and should be ignored. The low byte is set based on the state represented. The valid values are 0 (pending), 16 (running), 32 (shutting-down), 48 (terminated), 64 (stopping), and 80 (stopped).
- `instance-state-name` - The state of the instance (pending | running | shutting-down | terminated | stopping | stopped).
- `instance-status.reachability` - Filters on instance status where the name is reachability (passed | failed | initializing | insufficient-data).
- `instance-status.status` - The status of the instance (ok | impaired | initializing | insufficient-data | not-applicable).
- `system-status.reachability` - Filters on system status where the name is reachability (passed | failed | initializing | insufficient-data).
- `system-status.status` - The system status of the instance (ok | impaired | initializing | insufficient-data | not-applicable).